# Is it appropriate to ask for lesson plans of a certain type?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/15005/desmos-assignment-make-a-graph-that-does-this) question today.

Essentially, I am trying to collect some more lesson plans of a certain type: "Desmos Make-A-Graph" projects. And I invite others to contribute to this collection.

I am a little worried only because it's a big list question and doesn't have a right answer and that can be met with some animosity (at least on Math.SE). If there is a more appropriate place to do this then I would love to know about it. I wonder if I can get desmos to contribute to the project.

Comment: Well, you'll see now. It's not very  clear what the point of posting to meta now would be. // Alright I see you mentioned the meta post in the main question, at least that clarofies the intent.

Comment: @quid I'll see that now because the question won't generate a discussion? Hmm... I thought maybe it was worthwhile to create a separate space for a separate discussion. If that discussion doesn't happen I am not sure that I have done much damage.

Comment: You post to meta a question that asks "Is this an appropriate question" for a question that you had already asked. That seems a bit backwards to me. I then understood that you preemptively want to create a thread, but also for this I do not really see the point. A **comment** on the main post, would have been sufficient; to include meta-discussion in the main post is something that should not be done. Finally since I am already complaining, how useful do you think is the title of your meta post or the body?

Comment: @quid. Ok. I can keep that in mind for future use. I modified the post in question in accordingly. To address what you said before the "finally"

Comment: To the part after the "finally": I dunno. What would be a better title or body? I suppose another route may have been to catch the meta conversation in a chat? I could leave a link to chat. That way there is a space for the conversation to go... Ok. Now I've added a sentence to the body+ changed the title.